# Complex Group By linq Query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have a question...
i have 3 tables...

> user(id,name)
>
> Answers(id,title)
>
> UserAnswers(id,user_id,right_answer_id,user_answer_id)

now i want to get user name and total score which is
count(where (right_answer_id==user_answer_id)) * 10
so result can be like this

> UserName Score
>
> Imran         20
>
> john          30

I don't have such experience in Linq. how can i do that?
i know in sql i can do like

```
select u.Name, 
       sum (case 
              when q.Right_Anwer_id = q.user_answerr_id then 1 
              else 0 
            end)
 from quiz q
 inner join [User] u 
 on u.id = q.user_id
 group by u.Name,
          q.test_id
 having q.test_id = 1
```

Classes:

```
class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
}

class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

class UserAnswers
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public int user_answer_id { get; set; }
    public int right_answerr_id { get; set; }
    public virtual Answer Answer { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So you are asking how to do a `Linq` statement? Do you already have the 3 tables you would need to perform the query? If so please add to your question the results of each table...

Comment: bro i have added there name and schema

Comment: We need the code of classes so we see which navigation properties can be used.

Comment: I have edit classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also add a navigation property `User.UserAnswers` you can use this query:

```
from u in context.Users
where u.UserId == userid
select new
{
    u.Name,
    Score = u.UserAnswers
             .Count(ua => ua.user_answerr_id == ua.right_answerr_id) * 10
}
```

I don't see a `TestId` property in `UserAnswer` (please use the singular name for the class), or anywhere, so this `test_id = 1` condition in your SQL can't be applied in LINQ (yet).

Comment: Great that's what I am looking thanks mate. apart from where it's almost same what i need